# json parser not working in froyo and gingerbread but works on ics

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have a JSON Parser class that sends an Httppost if there is optional argument passed to it.

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, Object... params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        if(params.length > 0){
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity((List<? extends NameValuePair>)params[0]));
        }

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();       


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

This works in my ICS and JellyBean devices but not on Froyo and Gingerbread.
The error message is:

```
10-21 13:49:10.348: E/Buffer Error(471): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
10-21 13:49:10.348: E/JSON Parser(471): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Can somebody help me with this please? does froyo and gingerbread only supports httpGet??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny enough when I tried to test it in my Froyo and gingerbread emulator in ubuntu, it works. However when I tried to do it in windows it doesn't work at all. So this is officially CLOSED :)

Answer (score 0):

First check the file that your calling this json string from for invalid characters that will disrupt the json format. That was happening to me when i had this same problem getting data from php file, my php file was sending some extra errors which caused the parsing to jSONObject to fail

```
   try {
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
```

so that is how i got an error there

Comment: 10-21 13:49:10.348: E/JSON Parser(471): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of. That's the error message. I can just use this parser in ICS and jellybean but not in froyo and gingerbread devices

Comment: Oh it seems then you probably have to go about this another way

Answer (score 0):

try to put it in asynctask

example

```
private class PermissionEnableAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object[]>
{
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = null;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PermissionList.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(Constant.MSG_PROGRESSBAR_WAITING);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object[] doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        try
        {
            String Url = "your URL";
                    //your logic
        return yourlogic;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;    
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object[] object)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(object);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        try 
        {
                            your logic          
                    }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```